# Unexpected (too low) power consumption for a 24 V 1 meter LED strip

Tags: current, led-strip, 24v

I have a LED strip configuration that basically works, but when measuring something doesn't add up.

- The strip is 1 meter, 60 LEDs (SMD5050), 24 V, claimed as consuming 15 W per meter. When I google with this specifications (the LED type, density, voltage), basically all results show more or less the same power consumption. Just to be sure I measured the size of a led (5 mm x 5 mm) and the density (60 per meter as claimed)
- The power is 24 V, rated as 24 W switching type.

Connected this configuration is working, the light is on, no blinking or anything else.
The problem is that when I insert socket watt-meter it shows 6 W consumption. Just to be sure, I checked the DC output from the supply with a multi-meter, it shows 230 mA and 23-24 V so almost the same 6 W.

What can be wrong with this configuration and mainly why its faulty state doesn't lead to non-working or semi-working setup?

**Update 1**:

The cut from the LED strip in question
[image: The cut from the LED Strip in question]

**Update 2**:

Measured the voltage across the resistor and the LED (thanks to @Unimportant, for the suggestion), the numbers are 1.46 V and 2.86 V respectively.  Also previously the output of the power supply was measured as 23V / 230 mA. Below is my equations probably confirming a low-output SMD5050 24 V strip, I'm not yet ready to post it as my own reply given that I'm not so experienced in electronics.

- The current =
  (23 V - 2.86 V*6)/(4 * 62 ohm) = 0.0235 A
- Checking measured resistor voltage against the expected according to the current
  (0.0235 A*62 ohm) = 1.45 V (~ 1.46 V measured)
- Power consumption per cut
  (6 * 0.0235 A * 2.86 V) + (4 * 0.0235 A * 1.46 V) = 0.5405 W
- Power consumption for the whole 1 meter strip
  0.5405 W * 10 = 5.4 W
- Checking the measured output of the power supply against the expected value
  230 mA * 23 V = 5.29 W (~ 5.4 expected)
- Power consumption per LED (very bad for conventional SMD5050)
  0.0235 A*2.86 V =  0.06721 W

So, do this equations make sense?

Comment: Very common when you buy on eBay/Amazon/Ali and similar. Seems all vendors lie, just by different amounts.

Comment: If you test a 10 m length of LEDs, does it draw 60 W?

Comment: What size resistors does it use and how many LEDs are in series with each resistor?

Comment: @user1850479, from the photo I took, the resistors lists "620" and it looks like there's one resistor per two leds.

Comment: @winny, sure they can, but out of curiosity, where exactly? SMD5050 always lists more or less with the same specifications (V, A, W) no matter what the origin is. If it's the power supply that can not deliver then the leds are ok with less than optimal power, is it possible theoretically?

Comment: No, they used less capable LEDs and increased the series resistance to match.

Comment: What are the resistor values on your strip? Assuming 3-3.3V on the LEDs, you can find out how much current it is supposed to use

Comment: @bobflux, thanks, I'll try, my guess is that probably the LEDs in this strip are indeed cheap ones with 0.1W consumption (despite the package claim) then 6W working setup can be explained

Comment: Looks like groups of 3 LED's in series with 2x 62 ohms. Can you measure the voltage across a single LED, and across 1 of those 62 ohm resistors?

Comment: @Unimportant, hmm, 62 not 620 after all... Sure, 1.48 V across the resistor and 2.86 V across the one pair of the led contacts.

Answer (score 1):

The “ratings” on most of those led strips are pure fantasy. Unfortunately. Your measurements are reasonably in agreement with this assertion :)

The unfortunate aspect of such “marketing” is that novices are disproportionately affected when they buy things rated in a certain way, base the rest of their design on such ratings, and then have trouble figuring out “who is wrong”: their design or the numbers “on the box”.